# Why does an unchecked checkbox have a value of 'on'?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

(Also replicated in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL8q7msb/))

Given an HTML checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

The checkbox is displayed with no tick:

[image]

Logging the value of the element:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input').value)
```

Logs `on`, even though the checkbox is unchecked.

**Why is the value of the checkbox 'on', when the checkbox is unchecked?**

How can I get the correct value?

Comment: `on` is the default value, hence it's correct. If you want to check whether the checkbox is checked or not, use `checked` property instead of `value`. See at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwofjxzt/) how checkbox works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a checkbox is constant. It doesn't change (unless you change it with JavaScript). If you don't specify a value, it defaults to `on`.

The value has nothing to do with whether the input is checked or not.

In a traditional form submission, **only successful controls will be submitted and checkboxes are *not* successful unless they are checked**. On the server you determine if they are checked or not based on if the value is submitted or not.

You don't get different values with the input depending on its checked state.

---

If you want to determine if a checkbox is checked or not in client side JavaScript, look at the `checked` property, not the `value` property.

---

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => console.log({
  value: input.value,
  checked: input.checked
}));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="on">
<input type="checkbox" value="off" checked>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="foo" checked>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `value` if it isn't whether the checkbox is checked?

Comment: @mikemaccana — So you can tell which of a group of checkboxes is checked.

Comment: Could you explain further? Are you saying `value` somehow relates to `checked` but only for multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Consider https://jsbin.com/puqociquco/1/edit?html,output and then consider what the `animal` and `colour` arrays would look like when the data is submitted to the server.

Comment: @mikemaccana — Cats isn't the key. When submitted the server will get something like `animals = ['cats', 'bunnies']` (if those are the two things checked).

Comment: OK so answering the question: the purpose of `value` is a name that will appear in the array of values for the input `name`. If `checked` is off, the `value` won't appear at all.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#Value

"If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on, so the submitted data in that case would be subscribe=on."

Comment: But why is the checkbox unchecked?

Comment: This behavior is defined by W3C standard, maybe 'coz all ***input*** elements were designed for ***form*** from the very beginning, so just take it as a fact.  Added the "value" attribute when you want it to behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

"On" is the default value for the `value` attribute of a checkbox. When you send the form and the checkbox is checked, you will receive a name/value pair (checkboxname=on). This is where you need the `value` attribute (and the `name` attribute, of course).

What you actually want to do is:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('input').checked)
```

Comment: This answers my secondary question, but as a reminder, my question is: Why does an unchecked checkbox have a value of 'on'?

Comment: @mikemaccana Are the words "_the default value_" somehow inaccurate? `on` is the default value of a checkbox by [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#checkbox-state-(type%3Dcheckbox)), it has nothing to do with the state of the checkbox.

Comment: @Teemu The words 'the default value' are accurate but not enough to answer the 'why' part of the question. Your comment "because that's what the standard says" is a good answer, an insight into the rationale behind the standard would be even better.

Comment: @mikemaccana Well, the next statement is the "insight", and the rest can be found from the standard ... Anyway, it looks like Quentin has given a good explanation of why, why not to accept that?

Comment: Accepted Quentin's answer. As I mentioned earlier though you could add the 'why' bit from your comment into your own answer if you'd like an upvote.